# How to plot heatmap in Julia

Tags: julia, histogram, heatmap

I have a (21,100)-array and want to plot it as 2D-Histogram (heatmap).
If I plot it naively with `histogram2d(A, nbins= 20)` it only plots the first 21 points.

I tried to loop it, but then I had 100 histograms with 21 points. 
Another idea would be to put the data in a (2100)-array but this seems like a bad idea.

Addition:
I have a scatter plot/data and want it shown as a heatmap. The more points in one bin the "darker" the color. 
So I have 21 x-values each with 100 y-values.

Comment: A 2D histogram essentially plots correlations between two data vectors, as in `histogram2d(randn(1_000), randn(1_000))`, so it expects them both to be the same length. A heatmap is different in that it directly uses the dimensions of `A` and then colour codes the values in each `[i, j]` location of your matrix (check `heatmap(A)`) - could you clarify what your array is and what you would expect a histogram to do with a 21x100 matrix?

Comment: I think you just want a heat map.

Comment: I clarified what I mean above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here it is a typical scenario for a heatmap plot:

```
using Plots
gr()
data = rand(21,100)
heatmap(1:size(data,1),
    1:size(data,2), data,
    c=cgrad([:blue, :white,:red, :yellow]),
    xlabel="x values", ylabel="y values",
    title="My title")
```

[image]